# How can I handle audio messages in pyTelegramBotAPI?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm using pyTelegramBotAPI as framework to create a telegram bot.
I'm having some troubles with handle audio messages and I can't understand where I am wrong.

Here my code:

```
# If user send an audio and it's a private chat
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["audio"])
def react_to_audio(message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        bot.reply_to(message, """What a nice sound! I'm not here to listen to some audio, tho. My work is to wish a good night to all members of a group chat""")
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

i don't specifically know well how to use pyTelegramBotAPI because also i got problems i couldn't solve so i abandoned it for [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) which is better documented in comparison to pyTelegramBotAPI, has a bigger community, is more actively developed and also have an active [Telegram group](https://telegram.me/pythontelegrambotgroup) where you can directly ask for help from other developers using this wrapper.

So if you are interested to change to python-telegram-bot, the code for your bot would look something like this:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters

token = "" #Insert your token here


def message_handler(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Hello")

def audio_handler(update, context):
    if update.message.chat.type == "private": #Checks if the chat is private
        update.message.reply_text("What a nice sound! I'm not here to listen to some audio, tho. My work is to wish a good night to all members of a group chat")



def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    updater = Updater(token, use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher


    # on noncommand i.e message
    # Use this if you want to handle also other messages
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, message_handler))

    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.audio & ~Filters.command, audio_handler))

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Run the bot until you press Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here are also some [official examples](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/README.md) of bots made with this wrapper and the that you can use to better understand the wrapper, if you want more info regard this feel free to DM me on telegram @Husnainn.

Comment: Welcome to SO Husnain. This is not an answer to their question about using pyTelegramBotAPI.

Comment: Thank you, i know that and in fact i wrote that he could do this only if he is interested changing, thanks for the warning anyway, from the next time on i'll try to answer only things i know well, in this case it was the best thing i thought of doing.